# css rules does not refresh the style tag rules

Tags: javascript, css

I am changing the cssRules using the document.stylesheets the change happens but somehow the style tag doesnt seem to be updated, i need to update the textnode in the style tag of the iframe

here is a link to the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/1ahnxkhy/5/

```
var listCSS=".link1{text-transform:uppercase; color:red; background:#333; font-family:arial; font-size:14px; display:block}.link1:hover{background:red;}@media all and (max-width:640px) {.link1:hover{background:green;}}";
var iframeDoc=document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.document;
var style = iframeDoc.createElement('style');
var content = iframeDoc.createTextNode(listCSS);
style.appendChild(content);
var headTag = iframeDoc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];         
headTag.insertBefore(style, headTag.childNodes[2]);

var div= iframeDoc.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML='<a href="#" class="link1">link</a>';
iframeDoc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(div);

var object={
            property:"backgroundColor",
            searchRule:".link1",
            value:"blue",
            media:0,
        };

for(var i=0; i<iframeDoc.styleSheets[0].cssRules.length; i++)
  { 
       if(iframeDoc.styleSheets[0].cssRules[i].selectorText==object.searchRule)
       {
         iframeDoc.styleSheets[0].cssRules[i].style[object.property]=object.value;
         console.log(iframeDoc.styleSheets[0].cssRules[i].cssText);
       }
  }
```

Comment: Your fiddle works perfectly fine for me in Chrome, the background is blue, and is updated ?

Comment: agreed the change happens, butthe style tag is still not updated.If you inspect the style tag in the iframe the css for .link1 is not updated to having the background set to blue, also you could console the textNode of the css  console.dir(document.getElementById("myframe").contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0])

Comment: You're accessing and changing the  CSSStyleRule interface object, the style tag doesn't really change, the object does.

Comment: @adeneo Is there a way to sync them both?

Comment: Probably not, and why would you need to ?

Comment: the textNode contains the entire css for link1, so if i change to switch link1 and add link2 which would have a different style, I would also remove the text node associated with link1, hence I needed to make the update in the textNode within the style tag, so everything associated with link1 is in a single text node

Comment: I still don't really get it? Generally you should really almost never have to use `styleSheets` and `cssRules` they are oddities that come in handy in very rare and complicated cases, the rest of the time, just setting the styles the regular way is enough.